# Visual bug: edit and share popups

Tags: bug, design, suggested-edits, meta, sharing

If a user has low enough rep, and clicks the "edit" then "share" button under a meta question, this happens:

[image]

Weirdly, the reverse does not happen: if the "edit" button is clicked after the "share" button, the "share" popup will automatically dismiss itself.

Comment: What would you expect to happen? What is the suggested fix?

Comment: @SebastianSimon Dismiss the edit warning popup, then show the share popup

Comment: Is there something preventing the user from dismissing the edit warning popup? It's kind-of expected that you will dismiss it once you read it.

Comment: @Makyen No, but it's still a visual glitch.